# Database Driven Front End Controller / Page Management Good or Bad?

Tags: database, model-view-controller, front-controller

I am currently working within a custom framework that uses the database to setup a Page Object which contains the information about Module, View, Controller, etc which is used by a Front Controller to handle routing and the like within an MVC (obviously) pattern.

The original reason for handling the pages within the database was because we needed to be able to create new landing pages on the fly from within a admin interface and because we also needed to create onLoad and onUnload events to which other dynamic objects could be attached.

However, after reading this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249281/embedding-html-code-in-stored-procedures) yesterday, it made me wonder if we shouldn't move this handling out of the database and make it all file structure and code driven like other frameworks so that pages can be tested without having the database be a component.

I am currently looking at whether to scrap the custom framework and go with one of the standard frameworks and extend it (which is what's most likely right now), but I'm wondering whether to extend the framework to handle page requests through database like we are now or if we should simply go with whatever routing / handling mechanism comes with the framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually I'm pretty lenient on what I will allow to go on in a "toy" application, but I think there are some bad habits that should be avoided no matter what. Databases are powerful tools, with reasonably powerful languages via stored procedures for doing whatever you need to have done... but they really should be used for storing and scaling access to data, and enforcing your low level data consistency rules.

Putting business logic in the data layer was common years ago, but separation of concerns really does help with the maintainability of an application over its lifespan.

Note that there is nothing wrong with using a database to store page templates instead of the file system. The line between the two will blur even further in the future and I have one system that all of the templates are in the database because of problems with the low budget hosting and how dynamically generated content need to be saved. As long as your framework can pull out a template as easily from a file or a field and process them, it isn't going to matter much either way.

On the other hand, the post from yesterday was about generating the UI layer elements *directly* from the database (at least, that's how I read it) and not an unusual storage location for templates. *That* is a deep concern for the reasons mentioned... the database becomes locked to web apps, and only web apps.

And on the third hand, never take other people's advice *too* much to heart if you have a system that works well and is easy to extend. Every use-case is slightly different. If your maintainability isn't suffering and it serves the business need, it is good enough.